# How come this character sequence comparison returns true?

Tags: mysql, collation, mysql-5.7

How come the following SQL sentence returns `true` in MySQL?

```
SELECT 'SeP' = 'sęp';

mysql> select 'SeP' = 'sęp';
+----------------+
| 'SeP' = 'sęp'  |
+----------------+
|              1 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The character set and collation of my database is as follows.

```
mysql> select @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, @@collation_connection;
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database | @@collation_connection |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_general_ci   | utf8_general_ci        |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: We'd have to see the specs but I find it reasonable that both characters are considered equal in a general collation, not bound to any specific language.

Comment: You can try with `CASE WHEN` to achieve this functionality.

Comment: @SagarGangwal you can try, but it will not be much use

Comment: @Jagger You should look into `SELECT @@collation_connection;` because your query does not use a database... your query will use the table DUAL

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have just added `@@collation_connection` to my question.

Comment: @Jagger ok then Shadow's answer makes sense..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a case insensitive (`ci` at the end of the collation name indicates this) and generic collation, therefore MySQL compares the 2 strings in a case insensitive and usually an accent insensitive manner, therefore the two strings are the same.

MySQL manual on [Case sensitivity in string searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) says:

> For nonbinary strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT), string searches use the collation of the comparison operands. For binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB), comparisons use the numeric values of the bytes in the operands; this means that for alphabetic characters, comparisons will be case sensitive.
>
> A comparison between a nonbinary string and binary string is treated
>   as a comparison of binary strings.
>
> Simple comparison operations (>=, >, =, <, <=, sorting, and grouping)
>   are based on each character's “sort value.” Characters with the same
>   sort value are treated as the same character. For example, if e and é
>   have the same sort value in a given collation, they compare as equal.

To force case sensitivity use either case sensitive (`_cs`) or binary collations (`_bin`). To force accent sensitivity, you either need to use a language specific collation (in your case utf8mb4_polish_xxx), or a binary collation. Generic collations rarely distinguish between accented and non-accented characters.

Comment: Maybe it is not directly visible, but there is a special Polish character `ę` there.

Comment: @Jagger - it's visible but Shadow is right. Collation that you use adds the same weight to your polish accented character and latin letter `e`.

Comment: @Mjh nevertheless added some more explanation to make it clear that the collation treats the accented characters the same. The first sentence of the answer was overly focussed on case sensitivity.

Comment: @Jagger if you use `SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_bin';` and then `SELECT 'SeP' = 'sęp';`  your result is 0... utf8_bin is the best utf8 collation there is thats mine opinion.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Any way to pass that as a parameter to `mysql.exe`? What I have found is only `--default-character-set` parameter.

Comment: @Jagger that question should be in a new question not in this one will confuse future readers

Comment: @Jagger you can set the default value of any server variable in my.ini

Comment: `_bin` has `S` != `s` and `e` != `ę`.  Most `_ci` do the opposite:  `S` = `s` and `e` = `ę`.  `_cs` essentially does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`COLLATION utf8mb4_polish_ci` will treat these as "separate letters": `ą ć ę ń ś ź ż`

For example, `a` < `ą` < `b`.  In *most* other collations, `a` = `ą` < `b`.

```
mysql> SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_polish_ci;

mysql> SELECT 'SeP' = 'sęp';
+----------------+
| 'SeP' = 'sęp'  |
+----------------+
|              0 |
+----------------+
```

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) for details on how various collations differ.

Comment: Did I miss something?  Or misstate something?  Why the downvote?